# docker run immediately returns and does not show output of script.sh

Tags: bash, docker, containers

I have a simple `echo.sh` file with this: `echo "hello"` (with or without `#!/bin/bash` it gives the same error)

this command immediately returns even though there is a `echo.sh` in this place in the container:

```
docker run --rm -v $SCRIPTPATH/../:/home/project my_container --entrypoint bash /home/project/echo.sh
```

and there's no output, it should say `hello`.

I did

```
docker run --rm -v $SCRIPTPATH/../:/home/project -it my_container /bin/bash

 ./echo.sh
```

and it works.

This is how my Dockerfile ends:

```
WORKDIR /home/project
ENTRYPOINT "/bin/bash"
```

What am I doing wrong?

I found many places talking about running a script by doing how I did

Comment: There maybe something wrong with the file permissions or the location of the file. Run `docker run ... /bin/bash` and then inside the container run `pwd; ls -lh` to see the path and files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run an image, `--entrypoint` needs to be before the image name.

```
docker run --rm -v $SCRIPTPATH/../:/home/project --entrypoint bash my_container /home/project/echo.sh
```

Comment: Or just remove the entrypoint option with exec

Comment: why my command simply returns? What it does then?

Comment: Your command simply returns because `ENTRYPOINT "/bin/bash"` received null input.